# Looping through an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi all I'm trying to loop through an array using a password of 4 letters and an ID of 4 int numbers.

Thus far I can create the two 'keys' BUT I can't get them to search for the account on the arraylist I have despite it's creation. I really don't know how to fix this problem since the only way seems to be to just call for an 'If' statement or switch.

Here is where I have the code set up:

```
int acctID;
        int depositingAmount;
        //System.out.println("Input your ID and then your password to deposit money.");

        String inputID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your ID to begin depositing money.");

        acctID = Integer.parseInt(inputID);

        String inputPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your password to verify your account.");

        // int depositAmount;

        // do {

        for (int i = 0; i < bankAccounts.size(); i++)//Loops through accounts in my arraylist.
        {
            if (acctID == bankAccounts.get(i).getAccountId() && inputPassword == bankAccounts.get(i).getPassword())//If ID and password work are true then it goes in here.
            {

                String depositAmount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input how much money you want to "
                        + "input");//An here is where you would be able to spit out how much money to deposit.

                depositingAmount = Integer.parseInt(depositAmount);

                bankAccounts.get(i).deposit(depositingAmount);

                break;

            }
        }
```

Like you can see the loop in theory is suppose to go "Oh okay lets me start going though all of the accounts in the list until I get to yours" and when it finds it "oh hey I found your account, here let me give you the deposit feature". Sorry if I tried to simplify it too much in this paragraph its just that this problem is frustrating me too no end because I know that if I can solve this then the rest of my project is done. I have a withdraw feature also but that's basically the same thing but playing with different methods on the same class.

EDIT: Here are the constructors

```
public  BankAccount() {//ADDED TWO PARAMETERS
        //NO ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR
        accountId = (int) (Math.random() * 9000) + 999;
        //RANDBETWEEN
        setAccountBalance(0);
        Random passcode = new Random();
        //char charcs = (char)(passcode.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    //Added string. 
        String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int length = chars.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
            password += chars.split("")[ (int) (Math.random() * (length - 1)) ];}
    }

    public  BankAccount(double accountBalance) { // ONE ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR
        accountId = (int) (Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
        setAccountBalance(accountBalance);
        //Random passcode = new Random();
        //password = (String) (passcode.nextInt(26)) + 'a';
        //NEED A VARIABLE TO PASS IN
        //4 Digit password

        String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int length = chars.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
            password += chars.split("")[ (int) (Math.random() * (length - 1)) ];}

    }
```

An here are the getters..

```
public int getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
```

Also here are the fields I created..

```
private int accountId;

    private double accountBalance;

    private static double annualInterestRate = 0.045;

    private static java.util.Date dateCreated = new java.util.Date();

    private String name;

    private String password = "";
```

Here is where I stand with the If statement

```
if (acctID == bankAccounts.get(i).getAccountId() && inputPassword.equals(bankAccounts.get(i).getPassword()))
```

I've seen the other thread that's been posted has a similar question but their answer of just putting .equals() is not enough. Unless i'm stuppose to just take out bankAccounts from the line.

EDIT 2: The entire code.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class BankAccount {



    private int accountId;

    private double accountBalance;

    private static double annualInterestRate = 0.045;

    private static java.util.Date dateCreated = new java.util.Date();

    private String name;

    private String password = "";

    public  BankAccount() {//ADDED TWO PARAMETERS
        //NO ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR
        accountId = (int) (Math.random() * 9000) + 999;
        //RANDBETWEEN
        setAccountBalance(0);
        Random passcode = new Random();
        //char charcs = (char)(passcode.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    //Added string. 
        String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int length = chars.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
            password += chars.split("")[ (int) (Math.random() * (length - 1)) ];}
    }

    public  BankAccount(double accountBalance) { // ONE ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR
        accountId = (int) (Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
        setAccountBalance(accountBalance);
        //Random passcode = new Random();
        //password = (String) (passcode.nextInt(26)) + 'a';
        //NEED A VARIABLE TO PASS IN
        //4 Digit password

        String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int length = chars.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
            password += chars.split("")[ (int) (Math.random() * (length - 1)) ];}

    }

    public int getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public double getAccountBalance() {
        return accountBalance;
    }

    public void setAccountBalance(double accountBalance) {
        this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
    }

    public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
        return annualInterestRate;
    }

    public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amountToWithdraw) {

        if (amountToWithdraw > accountBalance) {
            //putting together withdraw make sure to have a validation to stop ppl from going over.
            System.out.println("Sorry you cannot exceed the amount you have in your balance.");
        }
        else {
        accountBalance = accountBalance - amountToWithdraw;
        }
    }

    public void deposit(double amountToDeposit) {

        if (amountToDeposit < 0) {
            //deposits cannot be negative 
        System.out.println("You cannot deposit a negative amount of dallars.");
        }
        else {
        accountBalance = accountBalance + amountToDeposit;
        }
    }

    public double getMonthlyInterestRate() {

        int MonthsInAYear = 12;//method variable is small BUT just need to get results

        double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / MonthsInAYear;

        return monthlyInterestRate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String toString(){

        String bankInfo = " Password: " + getPassword() + " Account ID: " + getAccountId();

        return bankInfo;
    }
}



public class CurrentAccount extends BankAccount{
    private static float overdraftLimit = 100;
    CurrentAccount(){
        super();
    }

    public static float getOverdraftLimit() {
        return overdraftLimit;
    }

    // MAKE A SETTER FOR THE OVERDRAFTLIMIT
    public void withdraw(double amountToWithdraw){
        if (amountToWithdraw <= getAccountBalance()+overdraftLimit) {
            setAccountBalance(getAccountBalance() - amountToWithdraw);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error this transaction has been cancelled.");
        }
    }

}



public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount{

    private static double interest;

    public SavingsAccount (){
        super();
        interest = 0;
    }

    public void addInterest(){

        interest = getAccountBalance() * getMonthlyInterestRate(); //GETTING ZEROS FROM ACCOUNTBALANCE
        //CHANGE getAccountBalance with some other initial payment.
        super.deposit(interest);

    }

    public double getInterest() {
        return interest;
    }

    public void setInterest(float interest) {
        this.interest = interest;
    }
}

public class Bank {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner Restart = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static ArrayList<BankAccount> bankAccounts; // MADE THIS STATIC

    public Bank() {
        bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    }

    public void openAccount() {

        Object[] possibilities = {"Regular Account", "Savings Account", "Checking Account"};

        Object inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please pick an option from this menu: ",
                    "input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, possibilities, possibilities [0]);

            if (inputValue.equals("Regular Account")) {
                // Make a regular acct
                String inputName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input your name");

                BankAccount newBankAccount = new BankAccount();

                newBankAccount.setName(inputName);

                bankAccounts.add(newBankAccount);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account ID: " + newBankAccount.getAccountId());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Password: " + newBankAccount.getPassword());


            } else if (inputValue.equals("Savings Account")) {
                // Make a savings acct
                String inputNameSavings = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input your name");

                BankAccount newBankAccount = new SavingsAccount();

                newBankAccount.setName(inputNameSavings);

                bankAccounts.add(newBankAccount);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account ID: " + newBankAccount.getAccountId());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Password: " + newBankAccount.getPassword());

            } else if (inputValue.equals("Checking Account")) {
                // Make a checking acct
                String inputNameChecking = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input your name");

                BankAccount newBankAccount = new CurrentAccount(); 

                newBankAccount.setName(inputNameChecking);

                bankAccounts.add(newBankAccount);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account ID: " + newBankAccount.getAccountId());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Password: " + newBankAccount.getPassword());
            }

    }

    public static ArrayList<BankAccount> getBankAccounts() {
        return bankAccounts;//Moving this into the Open.Account?
    }

    public void closeAccount() {

        System.out.println("Hello give me the name of the" + " "
                + "account you would like to close.");

        String userName = input.next();// Gets input for first choice.

        // Ask for account id
        System.out.println("Please input your account ID");
        int userAccountId = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < bankAccounts.size(); i++) {
            if (bankAccounts.get(i).getName().equals(userName)
                    && bankAccounts.get(i).getAccountId() == userAccountId) {
                bankAccounts.remove(i);
                System.out.println("Account removed");
            }

        }
        // anyway, you would set the name probably in the constructor function
        // for that particular instantiation of the class
    }

    public void update() {
        // UPDATES MY ACCOUNTS
        for (int i = 0; i < bankAccounts.size(); i++) {

            if (bankAccounts.get(i) instanceof SavingsAccount) {

                ((SavingsAccount) bankAccounts.get(i)).addInterest();
            } else if (bankAccounts.get(i) instanceof CurrentAccount) {

                if (bankAccounts.get(i).getAccountBalance() < 0) {
                    System.out.println("\nThe Account: " + bankAccounts.get(i).getName() + " has been OverDrafted.\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }// ends update

    public void withdraw(){

        System.out.println("Input your ID and then your password to withdraw money.");

         int acctID = input.nextInt();

         int withdrawAmount;

        // do {

        for (int i = 0; i < bankAccounts.size(); i++){

            //input needed.

            if (acctID == bankAccounts.get(i).getAccountId()){

                System.out.println("We have found your account. Please input how much money you would like to withdraw.");

                withdrawAmount = input.nextInt();

                bankAccounts.get(i).withdraw(withdrawAmount);

                break;

            }
                        //  } while (input != 1);
        }
    }

    public void deposit(){
        int acctID;
        int depositingAmount;
        //System.out.println("Input your ID and then your password to deposit money.");

        String inputID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your ID to begin depositing money.");

        acctID = Integer.parseInt(inputID);

        String inputPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your password to verify your account.");

        // int depositAmount;

        // do {

        for (int i = 0; i < bankAccounts.size(); i++)//Loops through accounts in my arraylist.
        {
            if (acctID == bankAccounts.get(i).getAccountId() && inputPassword.equals(bankAccounts.get(i).getPassword()))//If ID and password work are true then it goes in here.
            {

                String depositAmount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input how much money you want to "
                        + "input");//An here is where you would be able to spit out how much money to deposit.

                depositingAmount = Integer.parseInt(depositAmount);

                bankAccounts.get(i).deposit(depositingAmount);

                break;

            }
        }
    }   
    }
```

An finally the class i'm running it on...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestBankAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello User.");
    Object[] menuPossibilities = {"Create a New Account", "Deposit", "Withdraw", "Display Balance", "Exit"};

    Object menuValues = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please pick an option from this menu: ",
                "input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, menuPossibilities, menuPossibilities [0]);
    while (!menuValues.equals("Exit")){

        Bank newBank = new Bank();
        // Bank newBank1 = new Bank();
        // Bank newBank2 = new Bank(); Do the same thing as below but switch out
        // bank1 and bank2 as a substitute.
        ArrayList<BankAccount> bankList = newBank.getBankAccounts();

            if (menuValues.equals("Create a New Account")){

                newBank.openAccount();
            }

            else if (menuValues.equals("Deposit")){
                newBank.deposit();
            }
            else if (menuValues.equals("Withdraw")){
                newBank.withdraw();
            }
            else if (menuValues.equals("Display Balace")){
                newBank.deposit();
            }
            else if (menuValues.equals("Exit")){
                System.out.println("Thank you for using our service.");
            }

        menuValues = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Since you did not pick 5 please pick another option: ",
                   "input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, menuPossibilities, menuPossibilities [0]);


    }


    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Please rephrase for clarity.

Comment: @AMACB - Yeah, he needs to present the entire code and the problem encountered!

Comment: Problem is: I can't cycle through the array and get into the if statement to make a deposit. I tried the method below and hit all keys when the account was made to no avail. @AMACB

Comment: Kindly post the entire code. Not in bits and strips.

Comment: @LancePreston  Okay I put it on. It's a bit messy becasue i merged 3 different classes together. "BankAccount"   "SavingsAccount"   "Current Account" are all different classes. The last 2 are extensions of the first.

Comment: In the getters - `public String getPassword() { return this.password; }`

Comment: I'll try it right now but isn't that what the setter is for? The compiler will complain if I have both in the same method. Can you explain your answer a bit more please? EDIT: By the way no dice.

Comment: We use `setters` to set some data. Whilst, we use `getters` to get the set data back. The `this` keyword refers the current instance (object). So, as to get the password of the instance (object) we are currently dealing with, we need to use `this` hence, `return this.password`.

Comment: Hmm. Well tried it  again just to be sure. Maybe the problem is just with how the code is set up? I know your an outsider to my code and can't really give me the whole story of what you think is wrong but do you feel like my code was set up correctly?

Comment: Question: do you mean set the if statement as "this.password" for the second part?

Comment: @JoeJack3man75 - If you can describe your project to me, I can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals` method to check strings for equality.

Comment: inputPassword == bankAccounts.equals(i).getPassword() Like this?

Comment: `inputPassword.equals(bankAccounts.get(i).getPassword())`

Comment: I still can't get inside of the If statement. I'll re-post with more code.